# How to create prepared statements in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

First is it possible, I think it should be as they're safer than raw queries and prevent sql injection.

But there is literally nothing I can find in documentation.

`sequelize.prepare` <- doesn't exist

`sequelize.query` <- exists

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Never Mind, The `sequelize.query` has an option called `replacements` that is escaped automatically.

> **replacements are escaped** and inserted into the query by sequelize before the query is sent to the database

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :search_name ',
  { replacements: { search_name: 'ben%'  }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
).then(projects => {
  console.log(projects)
})
```

Comment: It's so built-in you hardly notice it's there.

Comment: But is this really about prepared statements, like sending a `PREPARE` command to the server and then sending only the parameter values? This seems more simply about having placeholders in a query that will be parsed repeatedly by the server if sumbitted again with different parameters.

Comment: That's right, but remember sequelize is an ORM and not a DB driver.

Comment: How do you make replacements in sequelize literal?