# How to fetch string data stored as array in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json

I have stored some unique codes in MySQL as array in respective to user email, now i want to verify the user with email and unique code submit by user. I want to create a query where i can match email and unique id stored in database, to proceed the user.

Database Entry:

```
 ["BZFeWwnmr8Rm6tuu","daFJWZCEtp2WzxtD","VV80UQQZ1ym77h0m"]
```

I have tried FIND_IN_SET

This is the code for API, I have stringify the user entered data, where it returns the value if there is single unique value stored, But if i fetch array of unique code e.g, `["BZFeWwnmr8Rm6tuu","daFJWZCEtp2WzxtD","VV80UQQZ1ym77h0m"]`
the MySQL query not working.

```
exports.vr_client_detail = function (req, res) {     
    const JSON_DATA = 'application/json';
    if(req.headers['content-type'] === JSON_DATA){
         if (req.body) {
            var unique_string = JSON.stringify(req.body.unique_string);  
            var email = req.body.management_email;

                    db.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM im_vr_client_activation '+
                    'WHERE FIND_IN_SET(unique_string, '+"'"+unique_string+"') AND "+
                    ' management_email= ' + "'" + email + "'").then(function(app){
                            var arr = app[0];
                                return res.json({response_status:'success', response_code:185, data:arr, response:'Successfully fetch data.'})                                                         
                        });
        }else{
            return res.json({response_status:'error',response_code:10001,response:'Post data is empty.'});
        }
    }else{
        return res.json({response_status:'error',response_code:10000,response:'Post data is not a json type.'});        
    } 
}
```

The data returns nothing

```
    {
        "response_status": "success",
        "response_code": 185,
        "data": [],
        "response": "Successfully fetch data."
    }
```

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` only works with comma-separated values, it can't handle square brackets around the array.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you normalized your schema, using a many-to-one table to hold all the unique strings instead of putting them into a single column.

But if you can't do that, you need to remove the `[` and `]` characters so you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

You should also use a parametrized query to prevent SQL injection. See [How to create prepared statements in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242772/how-to-create-prepared-statements-in-sequelize)

```
db.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM im_vr_client_activation '+
'WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:unique_string, SUBSTR(unique_string, 2, LENGTH(unique_string)-2)) ' +
'AND management_email = :email', {
    replacements: { unique_string: unique_string, email: email }
}).then(...)
```

If you're using MySQL 5.7 or higher you can change the datatype of the column to `JSON` and use `JSON_CONTAINS()`. And in 8.0 you can use the `MEMBER OF` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response, I have alter my code with the suggestion but, i couldn't solve the issue.
Please suggest me, how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I had the arguments to `FIND_IN_SET` in the wrong order, try now.

Comment: Sorry, its not working,
I think one closing bracket also missed, after email: email
please have a look, 
 
:email', {
                    replacements: { unique_string: unique_string, email: email }})

Comment: The code only working with single value
 "O4hSDDL5hFgqv0Tz"
, not working with 
"BZFeWwnmr8Rm6tuu","daFJWZCEtp2WzxtD","VV80UQQZ1ym77h0m"
,
as well as
["BZFeWwnmr8Rm6tuu","daFJWZCEtp2WzxtD","VV80UQQZ1ym77h0m"]

Comment: Works here with multiple values: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dhhn91BVX7cbKHjSQ6a6R5/0