# show data after inserted using sequelize raw queries in express

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to send the inserted data with raw queries using sequelize then show it. Below is my code:

```
const c_product_post = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const sql = `INSERT INTO products (p_name, p_price, p_stock, p_review, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
    VALUES ('${req.body.product_name}', ${req.body.product_price}, ${req.body.product_stock}, ${req.body.product_review}, now(), now());`
    const postData = await Product.sequelize.query(sql)
    // await postData.save()
    res.send({
        message: "success add new product",
        data: postData
    })
}
catch (err) {
    res.send({
        message: err
    })
  }
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is that after the data is inserted then it will be shown (**see below image in red**):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RETURNING` clause to your query. Try this

```sql
INSERT INTO products (p_name, p_price, p_stock, p_review, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
    VALUES ('${req.body.product_name}', ${req.body.product_price}, ${req.body.product_stock}, ${req.body.product_review}, now(), now()) 
RETURNING *;
```

Please note that your approach is highly SQLi prone. Consider using prepared statements instead of text substitution.

Comment: Thanks @Stefanov.sm it worked, but sorry can you explain more about "Consider using prepared statements instead of text substitution". I didn't get what you mean or may you give me a better approach for my queries if you don't mind. I'm still new about this really sorry for extra question.

Comment: You can start diving into the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242772/how-to-create-prepared-statements-in-sequelize)

Comment: Thanks @Stefanov.sm I will dive into both links you provided, thanks for the help appreciated.